# How can I create Enum types in Matlab from a mex function

Tags: matlab, mex

I know it is possible to generate classdef .m files which describe the enumeration, however this will result in a bunch of files being generated and will be quite messy.
What I am looking for is a way to do this "in memory" without generating any files. I know I can create simple variables in Matlab using the mexCallMatlab or mexEval functions, but classdef doesn't seem to work with these functions.

Comment: Have you looked into [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html)? What exactly do you need to pass in and/or out of mex code?

Comment: [Java Collections](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-java-collections-in-matlab/) might be another possibility.

Comment: The mex code will need to automatically generate the Enum types based on an external schema. The mex function is used to read in data from a file and at the moment we just pass the enums values as Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) is likely your best bet even though it's nowhere near as graceful as basic enums. An example from the doc:

```
keySet =   {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'};
valueSet = [327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4];
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet)
```

You can even pass the object into your mex code rather than using `mexCallMatlab` or `mexEval` -see [`mxGetProperty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetproperty.html) and [`mxIsClass`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisclass.html), for example, amongst [others](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/access-data.html). I've done this successfully for `RandStream` objects.

Comment: Are you saying that it is impossible to do exactly what I want and this is the next best thing?

Comment: First, I'm taking your word that you can't get custom classes that create enums to work in the way you need -I haven't tried that. Second, my point about this being less graceful has to do with that fact that this solution requires the use of a more complicated class (a builtin one at least) than what would be needed with simple enums. The resulting object should work in the way you need though.